# Confirmação de status de serviço site ou host

Tags: linux, http, validação, libcurl

Montei esse script para rodar em Linux, porém ele não esta funcionando do modo que esperava.

Estou utilizando o `curl` para poder encontrar o estado da conexão HTTP.

Ele me retorna:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Mais alguns conteúdos do site http...
```

Este é o script:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl-v --head --output /dev/null http://site:port/folder >> relatorios.txt
if ! HTTP_CODE=200 do
echo "operando servico web"; then
echo "Serviço Online"
else
echo "Serviço Offline"
exit 1
fi
exit
```

Esperava que ele respondesse com serviço online código 200 quando o mesmo está operando na rede, e serviço offline com qualquer outro código que é denominado quando uma página da internet não está disponível, 404, 500 etc..

Desliguei a máquina de teste para validar se a mensagem apareceria offline mas ainda assim mostra online. Precisaria que ele me mostrasse o status de quando está OK e se por qualquer outra razão a página sair do ar, reportar informando que a página está fora. Gostaria de usar este campo de resultado `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` pois ele muda quando a página esta fora.

Fiz esse script no terminal pelo `vi`, gostaria de usar o `curl` para verificar o status da página da web, mas não saiu como esperado. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar assim:

```
#!/bin/bash

HTTP_CODE=$(curl -o relatorios.txt  -L -s -w "%{http_code}" http://www.yoursite.com/pagina.html)

if [ "$HTTP_CODE" == "200" ]; then
        echo "operando servico web"
        echo "Serviço Online"
else
        echo "Serviço Offline"
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Validado a ação aplicada, obrigado :-)

Comment: blz. Marque como resposta útil (setinha acima), please! :-)

Answer (score 0):

aki um exemplo mano! nao consigo formata o texto nesse site desculpa! mais ja deve ajuda no seu problema!

status=$(curl -s --head google.com.br | awk  '$2  ~  "200"  ')

if [ -n  "$status" ]; then

echo "operando servico web"

echo "Serviço Online"

else

echo "Serviço Offline";exit 1

fi

exit

Comment: apresentou problema de execução na line 3 option"-n" a mensagem /diretorio não encontrado/

Comment: uai mano esse msm codigo funcionou aki!!!  mais de toda forma vi que ja achou a solução!/ peço desculpas si nao pude ajuda!!

Comment: Certo, agradeço pela ajuda. vlw man